# Trying to use delays in a loop while waiting for a response

Tags: c#, while-loop, timer, sleep

I'm very new to C# and have started to create a little text-based game in the console before I get into the more technical stuff. On my start menu, I was looking to make a simple flashy `'Press Enter to continue'`, which loops on and off until the user presses Enter.

```
while (!enter)
{
    WhiteText();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 15);
    Console.WriteLine("[Press 'Enter' to start game]");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    BlackText();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 15);
    Console.WriteLine("[Press 'Enter' to start game]");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Essentially I want that repeating while I check if the user has actually pressed enter. I used an if statement with `ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();` which then checks if they've pressed enter. My problem is that I can't seem to get both to run together. Is this something that's even possible in the console.

I'm really hoping I made this clear with my limited knowledge, any help or insight on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: "I'm very new to C#" - then do not waste your time on making the Console do things it really wasn't intended for. That is not as 'beginner' as it looks.

Comment: Find some projects that you can do with ReadLine and WriteLine.

Comment: Well `ReadKey()` will block - i.e execution will not continue to the next line until it returns, which it won't do until a key has been pressed.  Instead you can check  [`Console.KeyAvailable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Console_KeyAvailable) inside your loop to see if a key has been pressed, then act upon it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Console.KeyAvailable before reading the key.
But when the user presses enter the input will be processed only after the end of the Thread.Sleep . So it'll feel slow to the user

```
bool show = true;
while (true)
{
    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            break;
    }

    Console.ForegroundColor = show ? ConsoleColor.White : ConsoleColor.Black;

    Console.SetCursorPosition(47, 15);
    Console.WriteLine("[Press 'Enter' to start game]");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(show ? 2000 : 1000);
    show = !show;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you, I'm sure i can speed up the on/off to make it a bit more reactive for the user. Thanks for the explanation too.